# pandas convert integer to time

Tags: pandas, time

I have time column in seconds like this

```
100
100000
235900
```

I want to convert to time format, i.e.

```
00:01
01:00
23:59
```

I have tried

```
time = pd.to_datetime(temp['time'], format='%H%M%S').dt.time
```

but it throw

```
ValueError: time data '0' does not match format '%H%M%S' (match)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) with convert integers to strings:

```
time = pd.to_datetime(temp['time'].astype(str).str.zfill(6), format='%H%M%S').dt.time
print (time)
0    00:01:00
1    10:00:00
2    23:59:00
Name: time, dtype: object
```

If want timedeltas:

```
s = temp['time'].astype(str).str.zfill(6)

td = pd.to_timedelta(s.str[:2] + ':' + s.str[2:4] + ':' + s.str[4:])
print (td)
0   00:01:00
1   10:00:00
2   23:59:00
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Or:

```
td= pd.to_timedelta(time.astype(str))
print (td)
0   00:01:00
1   10:00:00
2   23:59:00
Name: time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```